# Background-image in Qt stylesheet doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

This should set the background to cats.jpg, but it doesn't do anything:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w; 
    w.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(images/ricepaper.png);");;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I thought that it could be a problem with the image location since changing the widget's background-color works fine, but the images folder is in the build-debug directory which I believe is the correct place. I've tried changing the image path, syntax, and styleSheet class and nothing has worked, any suggestions?

Comment: I think you have to write `"QWidget {background-image: url('images/ricepaper.png')}"`

Comment: What is this `Widget` class? Perhaps problem is in it. Do you override `paintEvent()`, for instance?

Comment: @andrea.marangoni- It looks like the single quotes aren't needed in the url (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html).

Comment: @hyde - The Widget class just inherits from QWidget, I'm doing a widget-based application. I've also tried setting it up in a window-based application so that w's type would inherit from QMainWindow and it still had the same problem - background-color works but background-image doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Qt Style Sheets Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html):

[image]

It should work. Probably the image file is not to be found where the program expects. If you're using Qt Creator, you should be aware that it builds the target binary in a separate directory (usually with a name like `build-yourprojectname-qtversion-Debug` or so). That's called *shadow build*.
You'll need to copy over your image(s) to the proper location relative to that shadow build directory, otherwise the program will not be able to find the file.

Your best bet is to embed the image in the binary as a resource.
I just tried this and seems to be working for me:

In `main.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QWidget *w = new QWidget;
   w->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/resources/pixmaps/close.png);");

   w->show();

   return app.exec();
}
```

Note the `:/` part in `url(:/resources/pixmaps/close.png)`. That's needed for embedded resources.

In `resources.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>resources/pixmaps/close.png</file>

    ... other resource files go here
</qresource>
```

At the end of `testproject.pro`:

```
   RESOURCES += \
   resources.qrc
```

Of course you'll need to put the images in the proper location in your project directory so that the resource compiler can find it.
In my example,

```
 resources/
 ├── pixmaps
 │   ├── application.png
 │   ├── cancel.png
 │   ├── close.png    <--Here
 ...
```

[image]